# Spectacular approximation to $\sum_{k=1}^n \{k \log_2 3\}$ where the curly brackets represent the fractional part

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recreational-mathematics, approximation, irrational-numbers

As many of the questions that I have asked recently, this is related to my investigations in finding a standard mathematical constant that has 50% of its binary digits equal to zero. My approximation is good enough for my purpose (solving a small piece of the puzzle), but I think it is worth mentioning and study a bit further.

$\sum_{k=1}^n \{k \log_2 3\} = \Big(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log_2 3\Big) -h(n) + \epsilon_n$,

where $\epsilon_n$ is the error and $h(n)$ is an integer. More specifically:

$h(n) =\Big\lfloor \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log_2 3 - \frac{n}{2} + 3\Big\rfloor$.

The approximation also works great if you replace $\log_2 3$ by another irrational number, but it fails with rational numbers.

**Questions**

- In absolute value, what is the maximum value of the error (the error
  is always a very small integer)
- Is it possible to obtain an exact formula? The error, while quite chaotic, seems to exhibit near periodicity. It is shown in the picture below: the Y-axis is the error, the X-axis is $n$.

[image]

I actually obtained an exact formula, but it does not seem very useful and involves a recursion:

$\sum_{k=1}^n \{k \log_2 3\} =\frac{n}{2}+f(n)$ with $f(n+1) = 2f(n) - f(n-1) + a(n)$ and  $a(n)  =  \log_2 3 - 2$ if $\{n(\log_2 3 - 1)\} > 2 - \log_2 3$, $a(n) = \log_2 3-1 $ otherwise. The initial values are $f(1) = \log_2 3 - \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(2) = 3\log_2 3 - 5$.

Comment: Isn't this essentially just saying that the values of your sum are nearly-equidistributed $\mod 1$?  IIRC distribution of sequences of the form $\{n\alpha\}$ for irrational $\alpha$ have been pretty well-studied and I suspect that there's a connection to the continued fraction of $\alpha$.

Comment: I think it is more than that. Equidistribution provides a first-order, trivial approximation to the sum. Here it is a second-order approximation, and it depends on $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \{k \log_2(3)\} = $$

$$\log_2(3)\sum_{k=1}^n k - \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k \log_2(3)\rfloor = $$
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log_2(3) - \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k\log_2(3)\rfloor$$

So the meat of your question is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k\log_2(3)\rfloor \approx \Big\lfloor \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log_2 3 - \frac{n}{2} + 3\Big\rfloor$$

The [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) confirms this as for large $n$ we can say:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k\log_2(3)\rfloor \approx \sum_{k=1}^n \left(k\log_2(3) - \frac{1}{2}\right )$$

And

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\log_2(3^k) - \frac{1}{2}\right ) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \log_2(3)-\frac{1}{2}n$$

Your final $+3$ just offsets the bias from flooring, but lowers overall accuracy as all your errors are positive, rather than alternating as negative and positive. Better would be to only add $\frac{1}{2}$ to make the floor round.

Comment: Agreed. But I am still surprised how this approximation is accurate, and wondering if you can get a better one -- an exact formula indeed, that does not involve an infinite summation.

Comment: What I meant is that the standard approximation is $\sum_{k=1}^n k \log_2 3 \approx \frac{n}{2}$ and is less accurate. It must be less accurate since it does not involve $\log_2 3$ and provides the same (weak) level of accuracy wtheter the number is $\log_2 3$ or any other irrational number.